# Can You Help Me With This Logistic Difference Equation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, chaos-theory

In population biology, the following equation is the Pielou Logistic Equation, is used to model population with non-overlapping generations

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{\alpha x_{n}}{1+\beta x_{n}}$$

Show that

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} x_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{\alpha -1}{\beta},&  |\alpha| > 1,\\
0,&  \alpha = 1 \text{ or } |\alpha|<1,\\
\big\{ x_0, \frac{-x_0}{1+\beta x_0} \big\},&\alpha = -1\quad(\text{note: a two cycle})
\end{cases}
$$

To be honest, I am not sure where to begin to return. I tried to use the substitution $z_n = \frac{1}{x_n}$ to transform this logistic equation into a linear equation.

Can you please give me some hints or pointers in order for me to understand what I need to do. I am sorry the notation is a little bit confusing.

I appreciate all of the help.

Comment: "I tried to use the substitution $z_n = \frac{1}{x_n}$ to transform this logistic equation into a linear equation. " Did you actually try this? This is an excellent idea. And what did you find then? More precisely: what prevented you to find a full solution once you had started along this path?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fractional linear transformation (a [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), when considered as a map on the complex numbers).  Iterating these can be done using the representation of these using $2 \times 2$ matrices.  If 
$f(x) = \dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ corresponds to the matrix $A = \pmatrix{a & b\cr c & d\cr}$, then the $n$'th iterate $f^{n}$ corresponds to the $n$'th power of the matrix: $A^n$.